# What kind of tool is Apache Airflow (FBP, ETL, Other ...)?

Tags: python, etl, airflow

What distinguises AirFlow from a FBP (Flow based Programming) tool like Node-Red for example ?

Is Airflow an ETL (Extract, Transform, Load)  tool ? Is it an FBP tool ? Both ?

If it's not an FBP tool, what are the advantages/disadvantages over FBP ?

NB : I noticed that Airflow graph are DAG ? is it a limitation (regarding what is possible with an FBP tool ?)

Thanks !

Comment: Airflow is a "smart scheduler" it can be used to schedule ETLs.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/): Airflow is a platform to programmatically author, schedule and monitor workflows.

The design principles of Airflow are:

- Dynamic: Airflow pipelines are configuration as code (Python), allowing for dynamic pipeline generation. This allows for writing code that instantiates pipelines dynamically.
- Extensible: Easily define your own operators, executors and extend the library so that it fits the level of abstraction that suits your environment.
- Elegant: Airflow pipelines are lean and explicit. Parameterizing your scripts is built into the core of Airflow using the powerful Jinja templating engine.
- Scalable: Airflow has a modular architecture and uses a message queue to orchestrate an arbitrary number of workers. Airflow is ready to scale to infinity.

It can be used for ETL and is also an FBP. It's a pretty versatile tool.

A DAG or [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) – is a collection of all the tasks you want to run, organized in a way that reflects their relationships and dependencies.